# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: EAP-TLS not working

Tags: ssl, 802.1x, freeradius

I'm setting up RADIUS server using FreeRADIUS and self-signed certificate. Tested using `eapol_test` and successfully logged in. But when I'm trying to add a PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to the network, it failed to pass EAP-TLS authenticate. But if I set auth-type of Ubuntu supplicant to `PEAP` or `TTLS`, it works as expected.

Dig into the `radiusd -X` logs and found that Ubuntu supplicant **never** sent out the client certificate. FreeRADIUS response with Access-Challenge for several times but Ubuntu supplicant just stopped after step (3), while `eapol_test` keep responding Access-Challenge and successfully login at step (6).

I've no idea what's going on. I'm not even sure whether it's the problem of Ubuntu or FreeRADIUS. Can anyone help me figure out what exactly is going on ?

Attachments:

1. FreeRADIUS log for Ubuntu login: https://pastebin.com/80ApMUeN
2. FreeRADIUS log for `eapol_test`: https://pastebin.com/yfFKaL1H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of problem myself: **VigorSwitch G2100** L2 Switch. Replaced it with another L2 Switch from other vender, and EAP-TLS supplicant works as expected.

The vender have listed 802.1X support on its spec, but their customer support had admitted to me that they've never tested EAP-TLS.